# Popping a navigation controller in a tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have a tab bar `MainViewController` with a few tab bar buttons, the first being `View 1` which is a navigation controller with a stack of up to 3 or 4 children. The final tab bar button is `SettingsViewController`, with a function similar to 'Logout' within it, which calls a method on the AppDelegate which removes `MainViewController` and sends the user back to a login page.

When pressing the logout button on `SettingsViewController` I want the AppDelegate to set the selected tab to be `View 1` (which I've done), send the user back to the logon view (also done) but also popToRootViewController on `View 1` which is the bit I'm struggling with.

I've tried using the viewControllers property on the tabBar to grab a reference to the view controller at index 0 but that doesn't appear to be the correct way unless I'm implementing it incorrectly.

My most recent attempt:

```
// Fine
mainViewcontroller.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

// Not so fine
NSArray *allViewControllers = [mainViewcontroller.tabBarController viewControllers];
View1 *vc = [allViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[vc.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Another attempt at just iterating through all view controllers in the tab and popping to the root which equally doesn't seem to work:

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in mainViewcontroller.tabBarController.viewControllers)
{
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have a UINavigationController in view 1?

Comment: I do, yep, which is what pushes the additional view controllers in View 1. On logout, I want that navigation controller to be popped back to the beginning.

Comment: How exactly are you implementing it? have you tried casting the viewController that you get to your specific view controller class?

Comment: I've added my most recent attempt to the question @NikolaKirev.

Comment: if view1 is a UINavigationController you just have to call: [viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, Junior. I do that in both blocks of code above but when the tab is selected using tabBarController.selectedIndex, the view currently on screen for that tab is still one of the children view controllers, not the main navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closures sake... using exactly the same code I pasted in my question worked find when I recreated the tab bar controller programatically instead of in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the view controller you are trying to pop back from might not even exist as it might have been purged (temporarily) from memory? View controllers in tabs not visible can be removed from memory by the system if memory gets low.

To overcome this I would halt your current method at setting the selectedIndex. However, I would previously have set a flag to state that the app should pop back to root i.e. Bool shouldPopBackToRoot = true;

Then in viewDidAppear of the viewControllers check this flag to see if they should popBackToRoot and if so do the popToRootViewController from the viewController's viewDidAppear (and don't forget to reset shouldPopBackToRoot back to false).